# What is the proper way to change only one element in in css but the others remains

Tags: css, react-native

I have an element has these CSS properties, applied with Stylesheet option of react-native

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      card: {
        marginTop: 30,
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginRight: 50,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#74C8AF',
        borderRadius: 10,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
     })
```

I want to implement this "card" property to all my cards but just want to alter only `backgroundColor` property unique to each card. Is there any way to handle this just in one card object, without setting different card objects for each individual?

I tried to change style like this but it discards whole object and only applies backgroundcolor

```
<Card style={styles.card, {backgroundColor:"#9932cc"}}>

//...

</Card>
```

Comment: If you have multiple style objects you need to put them in array, like `<Card style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor:"#9932cc" }]}>`

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<Card style={[styles.card, {backgroundColor:"#9932cc"}]}>
```

instead of

```
<Card style={styles.card, {backgroundColor:"#9932cc"}}>
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually do something along the lines of:

`<View style={this.jewelStyle()} />`

```
jewelStyle = function(options) {
   return {
     borderRadius: 12,
     background: randomColor(),
   }
 }
```

Every time View is rendered, a new style object will be instantiated with a random color associated with it. Of course, this means that the colors will change every time the component is re-rendered, which is perhaps not what you want. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
var myColor = randomColor()
<View style={jewelStyle(myColor)} />
```

```
jewelStyle = function(myColor) {
   return {
     borderRadius: 10,
     background: myColor,
   }
 }
```

Comment: interesting approach but that's not what I asked for. thanks anyway